# MYSQL: Insert one table into the beginning of another and set the auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql

I have php-script, which every 30 sec post the

- current date_time (starts from the 2016-01-27, see below)
- and corresponding some real-time data (Cian)

to the MYSQL-table **A** (about 100K columns). The table **A** looks as follows (sql_id is the AUTO_INCREMENT column number):

[image]

Also, I have the table **B** (about 100K columns), which consist of the same data as **A**, but for the previous period (before the 2016-01-27). So, **A** starts exactly from the moment, then **B** was finishing.

Finally I need to have one table, with joined data and:

- name **A** (it used by php-script and I couldn’t change the name inside php)
- B-data should be before A-data (so, **B** table should be insert into the benining of **A** and data will be in chronological sequence)
- AUTO_INCREMENT sql_id should be continuous and set to the [sql_id (B) + sql_id (A) + 1]. So, the next sql_id for the php-script will automatically be correct

What will be the best way to do that during 30 sec (before script post the next data)?

Comment: wrote my Answer. It should be very fast. Do you need the SQL Commands, too? Then perhaps post the actual structure of your table

Comment: This is going to get out of control very soon, if you need to insert 100k records every 30 second to the fron of the table. What I do not understand why you want the ids in this order? The date_time field indicates the chronological sequence, the ids will be in reverese sequence. So, what?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is. It could be done, all via sql commands. So its very fast. Every step could be executed independently. But if you have a live system with traffic STEP 4 and STEP 5 should be executed in a transaction.

1. Create a Table with named C with the same structure as A and B
2. Insert the data of B in C but with primary_key = NULL for auto_inc

   `INSERT INTO C (sql_id,date_time,cian) SELECT NULL, date_time, cian FROM B;`
3. Insert the data of A in C  but with primary_key = NULL for auto_inc

   `INSERT INTO C (sql_id,date_time,cian) SELECT NULL, date_time, cian FROM A;`
4. Delete Table A

   `DROP TABLE A;`
5. Rename the Table C to A

   `ALTER TABLE C RENAME TO A;`

Comment: DDL statements cannot be executed in a transaction, they auto-commit any open transaction. Essentially, each DDl statement forms a single transaction that cannot be rolled back. Otherwise, it works.

Comment: Thank's @Kordi, it's work! But 4&5 steps I execute without transactions. Hope, were will be no any problem with that.

Comment: If someone accesses your table during this step, then table will not found error will occur.